# why default constructor is not used in value initialisation in c++

Tags: c++, default-constructor, value-initialization, default-initialization

c++ primer says :

> The default constructor is used automatically whenever an object is default or
> value initialized.
> Default initialization happens
> • When we define nonstatic variables (§ 2.2.1, p. 43) or arrays (§ 3.5.1, p. 114)
> at block scope without initializers
> • When a class that itself has members of class type uses the synthesized de-
> fault constructor (§ 7.1.4, p. 262)
> • When members of class type are not explicitly initialized in a constructor
> initializer list (§ 7.1.4, p. 265)
> Value initialization happens
> • During array initialization when we provide fewer initializers than the size
> of the array (§ 3.5.1, p. 114)
> • When we define a local static object without an initializer (§ 6.1.1, p. 205)
> • When we explicitly request value initialization by writing an expressions of
> the form T() where T is the name of a type (The vector constructor that
> takes a single argument to specify the vector’s size (§ 3.3.1, p. 98) uses an
> argument of this kind to value initialize its element initializer.)
> Classes must have a default constructor in order to be used in these contexts. Most
> of these contexts should be fairly obvious

```
class foo{
public :
    int data;
    foo() = default;
};

int main(){
    std::vector<foo> fvec1;
    std::vector<foo> fvec2(4,foo(2));
    foo f[5]{1,2,4};
    std::cout << fvec2[1].data << " " << f[4].data << std::endl;
}
```

Output :

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘foo::foo(int)’
    std::vector<foo> fvec2(4, foo(2));
                              ^
error: could not convert ‘1’ from ‘int’ to ‘foo’
       foo f[5]{1,2,4};
                ^
```

But if we remove the following line

```
foo() = default;
```

the code works, while synthesised default constructor is used, why not a default constructor declared as default, why I am not getting the default behaviour though declared default.
And if possible can any one provide examples for above reasons said by 'c++ primer', because it is so confusing.

standard : c++ 20
compiler : g++-12, clang++-15

Comment: What version of C++ are you compiling against, that will matter.

Comment: updated c++ standard as pointed by 
@NathanOliver

Comment: Because in C++20 when you remove the defaulted ctor, it becomes an aggregate and there is **parenthesis aggregate initialization** in c++20

Comment: @semicolon_missing Keep in mind that the book you're using is C++11 only while you're compiling your program using C++20.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So we have a couple of things going on here.  First is that `foo` in the form of

```
class foo{
public :
    int data;
};
```

is an [aggregate](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization).  An aggregate can be initialized with `{}` and beginning in C++20 that was expanded to include `()` for initialization as well.  That means in

```
std::vector<foo> fvec2(4,foo(2));
//and
foo f[5]{1,2,4}
```

that you aggregate initialize the objects.

When you change `foo` to

```
class foo{
public :
    int data;
    foo() = default;
};
```

You no longer have an aggregate because you have a user declared constructor.  This means that to value initialize it you need to provide a constructor that takes in the value(s) that are needed to construct the class.  You do that by adding a constructor like

```
class foo{
public :
    int data;
    foo() = default;
    foo(int data_) : data(data_) {}
};
```

Comment: There are already plenty of duplicates for this.

Comment: @user12002570 I don't think there are many that also explain that `()` is usable in aggregate initialization since it is a pretty new feature.  If you find one go ahead and close it and I'll delete my answer.